# How to count the number of times an alphabet appears in a string of a row and save the value in another column using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, counter

I have a data frame-

| dnaseq |
| --- |
| CCGGTA |
| ATGCGT |

I want to the number of occurrence of 'C' in dnaseq and save the value in 'Count'. The result should look something like -

| dnaseq | Count |
| --- | --- |
| CCGGTA | 2 |
| ATGCGT | 1 |

```
count = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = row['dnaseq']
    b = list(a)
    for i in b:
      if i == 'C':
        count = count + 1
    df['Count'] = count
```

This just gives me the total count of 'C' in the whole dataframe and not individual value of each row.

I also tried another code-

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = row['dnaseq']
    b = Counter(a)
    df['Count'] = b['C']
```

but it just puts the last value counted in all the rows.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this code?
Thank you.

Comment: Use `df['Count'] = df['dnaseq'].str.count('C')`

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried so many different things but not this.